# Ratchet PHP Websockets: Private messaging (control who messages are being sent to)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, websocket, ratchet

Got another question.
I am starting to get used to how the websocket works.
I have even managed to implement communication cross domain.
But now I have yet to hit another milestone.

Here is a snippet from my current implementation

```
 public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg)
{
     $msgjson = json_decode($msg);
     $tag = $msgjson->tag;
     global $users; 

     if($tag == "[msgsend]")
     {

            foreach($this->clients as $client)
            {
                  $client->send($msg);    
            }
     }
     else if($tag == "[bye]")
     {

         foreach($this->clients as $client)
         {
              $client->send($msg);    
         }

         foreach($users as $key => $user)
         {
             if($user->name == $msgjson->uname)
             {
                unset($users[$key]); 
             }
         }

         $this->clients->detach($conn);
     }
     else if($tag == "[connected]")
     {
         //store client information
         $temp = new Users();
         $temp->name = $msgjson->uname;
         $temp->connection = $conn;
         $temp->timestamp = new \DateTime();



         $users[] = $temp;





          usort($users, array($this, "cmp"));


         //send out messages
          foreach($this->clients as $client)
         {
              $client->send($msg);    
         }           

     }
     else if($tag == "[imalive]")
     {
         //update user timestamp who sent [imalive]
         global $users;

          foreach($users as $user)
             {
                if($msgjson->uname == $user->name)
                {
                        $user->timestamp = new \DateTime(); 
                }
             }

     }   

}
```

Now my question is. As we can see, in the onMessage() function, and tutorials that I have done, I know how to read and parse JSON data, make sense of messages, tell who the message is coming from ($conn).....

But say when I send a message in a JSON packet, I want to include the nicknames of who the message is from as well as who the message is going to.
This will allow me to implement private instant messaging in both my social network that i am building and in chatrooms.

Instead of a for loop sending messages to all connected clients, I only want to send messages to specific ones. I know clients have a property ($this->$client->resourceID or something along those lines) but not sure how to incorporate it as a solution either. I also want users to maintain a connection as they jump to different pages on the website and even after a refresh, still be able to continue messaging. I assume each refresh disconnects the client. So I have to have a way where the server can tell each time who is who and where messages are coming from and where they are going to.

But yeah, private messaging. I dont want to have to send unnessecary messages to everyone or unintended targets. How can I accomplish this?
I hope my question makes sense. thanks.

Comment: If you think it is unfriendliness then I will suggest you do not understand the community and what the votes mean. A downvote (hover your mouse over the down arrow) means the voter thinks the question is not well researched or shows no effort. It is when you go off the rails that you draw extra eyeballs and suddenly your points level drops like a rock from a skyscraper. It is not personal, and these votes especially should not be. What I posted above said "if", not "you must". It is only a suggestion. If you're not getting help ask how you can get help. Don't cuss and scream and kick your feet

Comment: Its funny how my comments get deleted (because you know im right) but your replies are not. No. I do not understand the community or how my question was "not useful" or "didnt show any research effort" (as thats what it says when i hover over the down arrow).

The question in the other thread was researched. I spent days on it before I even asked about it on here. Eventually after the rudeness the other day I figured it out myself, and it was a much easier solution than anyone else here had suggested. However I wont be posting up the solution because you dont deserve the information.

Comment: Your comments weren't deleted by me, I do not have that kind of power. A mod is the only one who can delete comments. If your comments are not constructive, rude or offensive they will eventually get deleted. If you don't want to post a solution that is fine, it is no skin off of anyone's nose.

Answer (score 7):

Being able to uniquely identify users that connect to your WebSocket server and then being able to target those users, specifically, when sending out messages needs to begin at the `onOpen` callback where the connection is actually negotiated with the server.

In your `onOpen` method you should have some way of uniquely identifying the user on your system via some user id that's globally stored in your database, or persistence store. Since the connection is negotiated over HTTP you have access to the HTTP request via the `$conn->WebSocket->request`, which is a `GuzzleHttp` object containing the client's HTTP request information. You could use this to pull a cookie, for example, that contains some user id data or token that you can compare to your database to figure out who the user is and then store that as property of the `$client` object.

For now, let's pretend you're writing a normal PHP script where you do user authentication over HTTP and store the user id in a session. This session sets a cookie on the client's machine (*by default the cookie name is the session name, which is usually `PHPSESSID` unless you change it*) containing a session id. This session id can be used in your WebSocket server to accessed the session storage the same way you do normally in PHP.

Here's a simple example, where we expect a cookie named `PHPSESSID` from the request to capture the session id from cookie.

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // extract the cookie header from the HTTP request as a string
    $cookies = (string) $conn->WebSocket->request->getHeader('Cookie');
    // look at each cookie to find the one you expect
    $cookies = array_map('trim', explode(';', $cookies));
    $sessionId = null;
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        // If the string is empty keep going
        if (!strlen($cookie)) {
            continue;
        }
        // Otherwise, let's get the cookie name and value
        list($cookieName, $cookieValue) = explode('=', $cookie, 2) + [null, null];
        // If either are empty, something went wrong, we'll fail silently here
        if (!strlen($cookieName) || !strlen($cookieValue)) {
            continue;
        }
        // If it's not the cookie we're looking for keep going
        if ($cookieName !== "PHPSESSID") {
            continue;
        }
        // If we've gotten this far we have the session id
        $sessionId = urldecode($cookieValue);
        break;
    }
    // If we got here and $sessionId is still null, then the user isn't logged in
    if (!$sessionId) {
        return $conn->close(); // close the connection - no session!
    }
}
```

Now that you actually have the `$sessionId` you can use it to access the session storage for that session, pull the session information into your WebSocket server and store it as a property of the client connection object `$conn`.

So continuing from the above example let's add this code to the `onOpen` method.

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $conn->session = $this->methodToGetSessionData($sessionId);
    // now you have access to things in the session
    $this->clinets[] = $conn;
}
```

Now, let's go back to your example where you want to send a message specifically to just one user. Let's assume we have the following properties stored in the session, which are now accessible from the client connection object...

```
$conn->session->userName = 'Bob';
$conn->session->userId   = 1;
```

So let's say Bob wants to send a message to Jane. A request comes in to your WS server with something like `{"from":1,"to":2,tag:"[msgsend]"}` where the `to` and `from` properties of that JSON are basically the user ids of the user the message is *from* and the user the message is intended to be sent *to*, respectively. Let's assume Jane is `userId = 2` for this example.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) {
    $msgjson = json_decode($msg);
    $tag = $msgjson->tag;
    if ($tag == '[msgsend]') {
        foreach($this->clients as $client) {
            // only send to the designated recipient user id
            if ($msgjson->to == $client->session->userId) {
                $client->send($msg);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you might want to have more elaborate validation in there, but you should be able to expand on this from here.

Comment: the $conn->WebSocket->request->getHeader('Cookie'); is now changed to the $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie'); on new ratchet